# Creating a layer diagram with Base R plot

Tags: r, plot, polygon

I am trying to make a layer diagram in base R with three layers:
the area under the y1 line shaded cyan,
the area between the y1 and y2 line shaded yellow and
the area between y2 and y3 shaded grey.
I tried:

```
x <- 1:100
y1 <- 2*x+3
y2 <- y1 +4*x+9
y3 <- y2+ 1.5*x


 plot(x,y3,type="l")
 polygon(x,y3,col="grey",border="grey")
 polygon(x,y2,col="yellow",border="yellow")
 polygon(x,y1,col="cyan",border="cyan")
```

but this did not work.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, the `polygon` needs to return to the x axis, thus we need to add coordinate [100, 0]. I show `border=F`, but maybe yours is better. You probably should plot `lines` at the end if wanted.

```
plot(x, y3, type="n")
polygon(c(x, 100), c(y3, 0), col="grey", border=F)
polygon(c(x, 100), c(y2, 0), col="yellow", border=F)
polygon(c(x, 100), c(y1, 0), col="cyan", border=F)
lines(x, y3, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]